# How to retrieve payload in another redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

im checking the data existence for login and if success im posting job.... i want to retrieve payload data from signin action to another action. following is my action code and reducer code for 'signin'.
i want to retrieve in the 'createjob' redux action

```
 const signin = (cred) => {
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    var query = firestore.collection('Employers').where("email", "==", cred.email)
    query = query.where("password", "==", cred.password)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // Check if a document was returned
        if(querySnapshot.empty === true) {
           dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN_ERROR', cred});
        }
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            email = cred.email
            empname=doc.data().FirstName; 
            dispatch({type:'SIGN_IN', cred, payload:{cred, empname, email}});
            history.push('/dashboard')
        });
    }) 
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("No record");
        dispatch({type:'SIGN_IN_ERROR', err});
    });

}
};
```

my reducer code

```
const signin = (state = initState, action) => {

switch(action.type){
    case 'SIGN_IN':

    const empname = action.payload;
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log(empname, action.cred.email);
    console.log('====================================');
    return {
        ...state,
    authError : null,
    }    
    case 'SIGN_IN_ERROR':
    console.log('sign in error ',action.err);
    return {
        ...state,
        authError : 'Login Failed'
    }
    default:
    return state;
}
 }

export default signin;
```

i want to retrieve in the following action

```
 const createJob = (project) => {
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const empname = signin.action.payload;
    const email = signin.action.payload;
    var query = firestore.collection('Employers').where("email", "==", email)
    firestore.collection('Jobs').add({
        ...project,
        postedby:empname,
        postedon: new Date()

    }).then(()=>{
        dispatch({type:'CREATE_JOB', project});
    }).catch((err)=>{
        dispatch({type:'CREATE_JOB_ERROR', err});
    })
}
};
```

Comment: is createJob action called from signIn action?

Comment: no... its a different action file:)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a redux middleware in this case that gives access to the entire store at any point of dispatching the action.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already dispatching the payload with `SIGN_IN` action, you can store that data in store and in `createJob` action using getState you canread the payload from store

```
const signin = (state = initState, action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        case 'SIGN_IN':
        const empname = action.payload;
        console.log('====================================');
        console.log(empname, action.cred.email);
        console.log('====================================');
        return {
            ...state,
            empname,
            authError : null,
        }    
        case 'SIGN_IN_ERROR':
          console.log('sign in error ',action.err);
          return {
            ...state,
            authError : 'Login Failed'
          }
        default:
        return state;
    }
 }

 export default signin;
```

---

```
const createJob = (project) => {

    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const empname = getState().signin.empname; // getting from reducer 
        const email = signin.action.payload;
        var query = firestore.collection('Employers').where("email", "==", email)
        firestore.collection('Jobs').add({
            ...project,
            postedby:empname,
            postedon: new Date()

        }).then(()=>{
            dispatch({type:'CREATE_JOB', project});
        }).catch((err)=>{
            dispatch({type:'CREATE_JOB_ERROR', err});
        })
    }

};
```

Comment: i get this error => TypeError: Cannot read property 'empname' of undefined